# Directory.GetFiles with multiple filters, collect one string array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add new item to string array or I can keep in List. Can somebody show how to do this?

```
 string sourceDir = "C:\\Users\\ozkan\\Desktop\\foto\\"
 string[] picList;        
 string pattern = "*.jpg|*.png|*.gif";
 string[] filters = pattern.Split('|');

 foreach (string filter in filters)
 { 
    // I want to collect all files url in picList
    // Directory.GetFiles returns string array
    picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, filter);           
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try :

```
 string sourceDir = "C:\\Users\\ozkan\\Desktop\\foto\\"
 string[] picList;        
 string pattern = "*.jpg|*.png|*.gif";
 string[] filters = pattern.Split('|');
 picList =  filters .SelectMany(f=> Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir , f)).ToArray();
```